# event.preventDefaut() is not working on Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am experiencing an issue with my react app when I try to submit a form a request is performed using fetch, The request works well, but the problem is that the page always refreshes afterwards. I can't find the reason why this happens because I have another form on another page that works correctly.

Function submitForm:

```js
      submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let {
      email,
      password,
      nombre,
      imagen,
      imagenArchivo,
      url,
      descripcion,
      descripcionBreve,
      estado,
    } = this.state;
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", localStorage.getItem("token"));

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("nombreONG", nombre);
    formdata.append("urlONG", url);
    formdata.append("descripcionBreveONG", descripcionBreve);
    formdata.append("descripcionONG", descripcion);
    formdata.append("idiomaONG", "1");
    formdata.append("emailONG", email);
    formdata.append("passONG", password);
    formdata.append("imgONG", imagenArchivo, imagen);
    formdata.append("estadoONG", estado);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: formdata,
      redirect: "follow",
    };
    fetch(Constantes.urlSPRING + "/v1/ONG/intranet/editar", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => this.setState({ response: response }))
      .catch((error) =>
        console.log(
          error +
            "Ha ocurrido un error con la petición de de registro, intenteteló más tarde o contacte con el administrador."
        )
      );
    alert("gkjghjgjhgjgjhkghjgjh");
  }
```

The form(fragment):

```
        <form className="" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
          <div className="row fila-form">
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Nombre:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="inputNombre"
                name="nombre"
                value={nombre}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Nombre de la ONG"
                required
                autoFocus
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Email:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="inputEmail"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Email"
                required
                autoFocus
              ></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row fila-form">
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Contraseña:</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="inputPassword"
                name="password"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onKeyUp={this.contraseñas}
                title="La contraseña debe de tener una longitud de al menos 8 cáractares y de contener al menos una letra minúscula, una letra mayúscula y un número."
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Contraseña"
                value={password}
                required
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Repita la contraseña:</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                id="inputPassword2"
                name="password2"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                onKeyUp={this.contraseñas}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Confirme Contraseña"
                value={password2}
                required
              ></input>
            </div>
            <p id="errContraseña">{errContraseñas}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="row fila-form">
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Imagen:</label>
              <input
                type="file"
                name="imagen"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Imagen"
                value={imagen}
                accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
                required
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 text-left">
              <label> Url de la ONG:</label>
              <input
                type="url"
                name="url"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Url de la ONG"
                value={url}
                required
              ></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row fila-form">
            <div className="col-md-8 descripcionBreve text-left">
              <label> Descripción breve:</label>
              <textarea
                type="text"
                name="descripcionBreve"
                maxLength="320"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Descripción breve de la ONG"
                value={descripcionBreve}
                required
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-10 descripcion text-left">
              <label> Descripción:</label>
              <textarea
                type="text"
                name="descripcion"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Descripción de la ONG"
                value={descripcion}
                required
              ></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          {errContraseñas === "" ? (
            <button
              className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              type="submit"
            >
              Editar ONG
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button
              className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
              type="submit"
              disabled
            >
              Editar ONG
            </button>
          )}
        </form>
```

Comment: May be its refreshing as you are doing  this.setState({ response: response } in the fetch handler

Comment: is it possible for you to add the rest of your form?

Comment: I just add  the rest of the form. @Supercool Ithink that  this.setState({ response: response } is not the problem because the states affect to the render function it don't refresh tha page

Comment: Have you binded the function `submitForm`? You can directly change it to an arrow function.

Comment: Yes, I binded it

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you try placing your `e.preventDefault()` at the end of the code, this way it replaces the functions `return` (value of false) as you are not returning anything from the form.